# Using mod rewrite for images

Tags: image, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make a rewrite but after trying a lot of solutions, I decided to give up and ask it here.
Basically I want to rewrite "example.com/servers/srv_fr/urJq0H.jpg" for example to "example.com/urJq0H".
If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).jpg$ /servers/srv_fr/$1.jpg [L]
```

Comment: That seems to work fine, but is there any way to get rid of the extension name as well?

Comment: Modified in this way, should go to the majority of images:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+).(png|jpg|gif)$ /servers/srv_fr/$1.$2 [L]`

To delete an extension, you need to check all the calls arriving at, see if it is an image or other and see if it requires the user